# running docker from gradle: cannot pull image

Tags: java, gradle, docker

i have no problems running docker from cmd line:

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 -it --rm postgres:9.5.2`
```

but when i do it from gradle, using [dcompose plugin](https://github.com/chrisgahlert/gradle-dcompose-plugin), i got

```
Could not evaluate onlyIf predicate for task ':pullDatabaseImage'.
> Docker command failed: Certificate path (DOCKER_CERT_PATH) '/home/xxx/.docker/certs' doesn't exist.
```

my config:

```
plugins {
  id "com.chrisgahlert.gradle-dcompose-plugin" version "0.3.2"
}

dcompose {
    database {
        image = 'postgres:9.5.2'   // Required
    }
}

test {
    dependsOn startDatabaseContainer
    finalizedBy removeDatabaseContainer
}
```

what's wrong? how can i run docker from gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that docker uses Unix sockets for unsecured local communication but it requires custom certificates for network communication / IP sockets. plugin `com.chrisgahlert.gradle-dcompose-plugin` uses network communication, so there is no way to make it work out of the box (every developer that wants to run it locally would have to configure his docker). So I stopped using that plugin and switched to manually executing system command (`docker run ...`) from Java. This way no additional security configuration is needed.

Comment: Hi, can you accept your answer so that the question doesn't show as unanswered? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response.

Try using the latest plugin version (currently 0.8.0). This uses the latest docker-java library which is responsible for communicating with the Docker host. In this version it should be possible to connect to a local unix socket.

If that doesn't help: Try unsetting the environment variable `unset DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY`.